# JavaScript event for contenteditable elements

Tags: javascript, dom-events, contenteditable

Is there a way to capture JavaScript events for when a `contenteditable` element begins and ends editing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure *exactly* here, but aren't you after [`focus` and `blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Events)?  I'm not sure what else "begins and ends editing" could be translated to that has a different timing than those, unless you mean an event for every keystroke, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As Nick said, `focus` and `blur` will work, and in all major browsers. IE also has a number of related events (although none of these are implemented in other browsers as far as I know): [`activate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536787%28VS.85%29.aspx), [`deactivate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536922%28VS.85%29.aspx), [`beforeactivate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536791%28VS.85%29.aspx), [`beforedeactivate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536903%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [`beforeeditfocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536904%28VS.85%29.aspx)